# Unsatisfied dependency expressed error while running unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring boot application in which I declared a Component as shown below:

```
   public class Comp1{

   }
```

I wanted to make this a Singleton bean (Since by default the component is a Singleton I didn't add an explicit declaration).

I added a private constructor to the class.

```
  @Component
   public class Comp1{
      private Comp1(){
      }
   }
```

I have a Configuration class which defines beans.

```
   @Configuration
   public class Congfig1{
     @Bean
     public Bean1 getBean1(){
     }
   }
```

I also have the Application and Controller classes.

```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class App1{
   }

   @RestController
   public class Controller1{
      @Autowired
      private Comp1 comp1;
   }
```

My unit test case is shown below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,classes = {Config1.class})
public class UnitTest {
   @Autowired
   private Comp1 com1;
```

With the above code, if I run the unit test I will get the following exception.

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositoryMaster'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

However the application works fine when I run it as a Spring boot application.

When I made the constructor of Comp1 public and added a bean definition of Comp1 in Config1, the exception did not occur.

```
  @Component
   public class Comp1{
      public Comp1(){
      }
   }

   @Configuration
   public class Congfig1{
     @Bean
     public Bean1 getBean1(){
     }
     @Bean
     public Comp1 getComp1(){
     }
   }
```

Can somebody please explain the reason for this discrepany. I assumed that if component scan is enabled, then beans should be autowired in the application.

Answer (score 0):

1) As constructor private, spring is not able to create instance of mention component class 
   Comp1
2) once @Component is add on class, spring will try to create singleton instance default. 
   through DI where object required, inject object.
   you don't need to use even   @Bean public Comp1 getComp1(){ }